# Huge performance issues with nVidia GeForce 7100

Tags: nvidia, 12.04, performance

There are several reports that say that there are serious performance issues using 12.04 and nVidia 7100.

Are there any work-a-round in sight?

Comment: try open drivers, binary drivers, and unity 2d.  in that order.  i have an older nvidia dedicated card on my laptop that took some tweaking, but it works fine now.

Comment: Please provide a link to these reports, also test your computer with a live usb install or seperate beta partition and then report a bug in the normal way.

Comment: No problem with NVidia Quadro NVS 110M, which has an NVidia GeForce Go **7300** chip, I believe.

Comment: Right now I compine binary driver and unity 2, but its the media machine (connected to the familys TV) and neighter play channels thru webbrowser, Me-TV or xbmc work well with that configuration.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/962191
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/959677
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/961349
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/859979

There are several bug reports, I don't think another one will contribute something new. But reading between the lines, it may be some work-a-rounds.

Comment: It seems to be the patch for CVE-2012-0946 that is the problem. "Please do not use 295.40 or the security patch with GeForce 6, 7 or 8800GTX/GTS cards"
http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=178460

I have tried to install an older driver thru Synaptic, with no luck. I found 295.33 in launchpad http://launchpadlibrarian.net/98943873/nvidia-current_295.33-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb . This is my next step.

Comment: I have now tested older drivers, with no luck, 295.20 and 295.33. It seems to be problem may be booth in the driver and some part of the framework in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can you put this information in your question instead of burying it in the comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem (found in a discussion in ubuntuforum.org). I installed the old nvidia-173 driver AND downgraded xserver-xorg. After this XBMC, Unity and other GPU-hungry things started to work again.

1) /etc/apt/preferences.d/10xorg

```
Package: xorg xserver-xorg*
Pin: release a=oneiric
Pin-Priority: 1050
# So i can find dependencies for the older driver
```

2) /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
# New section
Section "Extensions"
Option "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

3) install nvidia-173 using synaptic or apt-get

Comment: Well... step 2 alone "fixes" the issue, but basically makes Unity 3D act like 2D, which kind of defeats the purpose of the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another bug report to add to the list:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/987469

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to 295.33 helped with my GeForce 7100. Everything works well now.

Type Ctl-Alt-F1, then:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-current=295.33-0ubuntu1~precise~xup1
```

I found this solution in this article: [Unity 3d no longer works after installing 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125608/unity-3d-no-longer-works-after-installing-12-04)

Answer (score 1):

my problem was with geforce gt630m with optimus technologies, and intel HD3000

Problem description: battery duration on linux 1 hour // windows 6 hours

After installing bumblebee, battery duration on linux 4.3 hours

instruction here: http://www.leanuxeros.com/linux/como-instalar-bumblebee-3-0-en-ubuntu-y-debian/

maybe you should use google.translator.com