# Ubuntu 12.04 responsiveness very slow on Nvidia 8800?

Tags: unity, 12.04, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity 3d no longer works after installing 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125608/unity-3d-no-longer-works-after-installing-12-04)

Just installed 12.04. This is the first time I run Ubuntu with the Unity UI, not a pleasant experience. The responsiveness is extremely slow (10s after a mouseclick), the screen flickers. All right after logging in. Switching the display driver from Nvidia current to post-release doesn't help at all. What now? Can't go back, but Ubuntu is useless to me right now.

What can I do?

(The system is a Intel 4x2.4Ghz with 4Gb RAM and a Nvidia 8800.)

Comment: Welcome on AskUbuntu! Just to know, could you edit your question to tell whether Unity 2D works?