# Desktop doesn't load after install Nvidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

When I load Ubuntu 12.04, it logs in with slight flickering, and proceeds to the desktop. With no Unity. Or Icons. I can right-click but that's all.

This started since I installed the restricted driver for my Nvidia card.

Comment: What Nvidia card does you system have? And is your laptop optimus enabled?

Comment: Use this solution it help me a lot
http://askubuntu.com/questions/125608/unity-3d-no-longer-works-after-installing-12-04

Answer (score 1):

When something used to work, and stopped working, it is known as a regression. Regressions are usually caused by a hardware or software change that didn't agree with Ubuntu. In your case, if you have not tried it already, uninstall the Nvidia driver. If it is so broken that you can't do that, you may have to boot from the Live CD to do it. Also, by "With no unity. Or icons", do you mean it boots into GNOME, or you just see the desktop background and nothing else? Also, other info, such as the driver version, graphics card model, and other specs could be useful. Remember, on AskUbuntu, there is no such thing as too much information. Anyways, I hope this helps, and happy hacking!

Comment: I just see the desktop background. Is it possible to uninstall the driver via the command line? I still have access to that.

Comment: Fixed it now. I used the jockey-text interface. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on what Rocket101 said, there's a problem with the latest NVidia drivers if you have an older card. Apparently they're working on sorting them out, but they made my own system so unstable that I uninstalled them and used the noveau drivers instead. See my post here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/126843/clean-install-of-12-04-results-in-constant-freezes-x-org-suspected

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for your infomation on this. Hopefully it'll get sorted soon enough....

Comment: Did the noveau driver work well enough to make use of the nVidia card? Stable?

Comment: As far as I can tell the noveau driver works just fine and are nice and stable - the only problem is that it won't use the 3d effects of my card so I'm stuck on Ubuntu 2d until NVidia sort out their drivers. I think they might have done it by now, though - apparently the package has been updated...